# How can I refactor a conditional statement that happens twice?

Tags: java, refactoring

Can I remove the second conditional to check if a course is full *and* improve readability?

```
...    
if (course.isFull()) {
  attemptStudentCapacityIncrease(course);
  if (course.isFull()) {
    // could not increase course student capacity
    return;
  }
}
// course is not full
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the function so that it returns false upon fail and true upon success.

```
if (course.isFull()) {
    if (!attemptStudentCapacityIncrease(course)) {
        // could not increase course student capacity
        return;
   }
}
```

You might also consider to modify the function to throw an exception upon failure, which you then handle like this:

```
if (course.isFull()) {
    try {
        attemptStudentCapacityIncrease(course);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // could not increase course student capacity
        return;
    }
}
```

But remember to use exceptions only for exceptional situations ;).

Comment: I'm thinking I might need to change the method name to doIncreaseStudentCapacity if I were to use this approach...

Comment: I would recommend that. Good naming is the most important thing in programming imho. To have "attempt" in a function name is usually a redundant thing. And just increaseStudentCapacity would be maybe a bit neater :).

Comment: I like the idea of having words like "do" for methods that return boolean values because it makes it clear the result of that method was whether or not that operation occurred. If I were to use increaseStudentCapacity, it seems like that function should "just work" and if it doesn't that would be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you can't change the API's:

```
int attempts = 3;
while (attempts-- && course.isFull())
    attemptStudentCapacityIncrease(course);

if (attempts == 0)
    return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also throw a custom exception.

```
if (course.isFull()) {
    try {
        attemptStudentCapacityIncrease(course);
    } catch (IncreaseCourseException ice) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I think that it is nicer than returning a boolean vlaue in attemptStudentCapacityIncrease, but it is less efficient, so it depends on how often the method is called in pratice (and what you think looks better)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like the boolean with the method name as it was, what do you think about renaming the method to doIncreaseStudentCapacity?